# Use a field in a list without use it in a datacard visible on form

Tags: powerapps

I wonder if it's possible to create a column in a sharepoint list, and put data in it, without "show" the datacard on my form.
Example : I want my column "AGE" to be fill with my user name. But I don't want to put the datacard on my form.

Currently, I have to put the datacard on my form, with Visible at false. But it's disturbing when I want to manage my form.

Of course, if you don't understand me, I can try to explain better :D

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill column with data that you got in your application, you need to add this in your form.
Also you can use calculated value option in your share point list where you can use data from other columns
[image: SP List calculated value]

[More about calculated value...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: That's really interesting. But if I put Title, I have this "a formule contient une ou plusieurs références à un ou plusieurs champs." (Formula contains one or several references to one or several fields).
I tried Title.Text, but then, it says fields doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you show me your column where you used calculated value and formula?

Comment: You need to add new column with type: Calculated (calculation based on other columns) (Add column -> More...)

Comment: Wonderfull ! Thanks a lot !